# Spring ExceptionHandler does not return valid response code

Tags: java, spring

I have such Exception handler in spring RestController.

```
   @ExceptionHandler(AuthException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleCustomException(AuthException ex, Writer writer) throws IOException {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    ResponseEntity responseEntity = new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    (new ObjectMapper()).writeValue(writer, ex.getAsMap());

    return responseEntity;
}
```

I expect result:
Content-type: application-json
Status: 403
And body:

```
{"date":"06-06-2019 18:36:34","errorCode":"102","error":"Login or password is not right","message":"Access denied"}
```

But result is:
Status: 200 and Content-type is not set. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this. This is a code snippet, modify it as per the requirements.

```
@ControllerAdvice
    public class GlobalExceptionHandler{
        @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
        @ResponseBody
        public ResponseEntity<?> handleCustomException(MyCustomException e) {        
            String bodyJson = "Fatal Exception while performing.";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(bodyJson);
        }
    }
```